# How I can remove symbols before specific symbols in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some string "Europe/Paris", how I can remove symbols before "/" in Swift? Must to be only "Paris".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
if let range = str.range(of: "/") {
    let res = str.replacingCharacters(in: String.Index(utf16Offset: 0,in: str)...range.lowerBound, with: "")
    print(res)
}
```

**OR**

```
let str = "Europe/Paris" 
let regex = ".*/"
print(str.replacingOccurrences(of: regex, with: "", options: [.regularExpression]) )
```